# transparency on ImageViews

Tags: android, transparency, android-imageview, transparent, alpha

I am trying to change some of the pixels (the white ones) in an ImageView to transparent, so that when I move the

ImageView over another ImageView I can see through the transparent pixels the image below (I move the imageView with an animation, changing its position). But after the processing, the suposedly transparent pixels are black and i can't see anything through them.

Here is the code to make the pixels transparent:

```
              private void transparentimage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Bitmap bitmapscr =((BitmapDrawable)myImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         Bitmap b = bitmapscr.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                for (int i = 0; i< b.getWidth(); i++){
                    for (int j = 0; j< b.getHeight(); j++){

                        if (b.getPixel(i,j) == Color.WHITE)         
                            b.setPixel(i,j,Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                }
            myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            myImageView.invalidate();



}
```

I have also set the imageView background to transparent.

Any ideas? I have been trying to solve it for a long time and I would apreciate any help.

Thank you so much

Julian

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is via the setAlpha command.

```
myImageView.setAlpha(50);
```